# Fetching records that having their monthly period of creation date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to grab all the records that have been created ℕ month ago, exactly the same hour. (age of the records should be only ℕ months, 0 days, 0 hour)

ℕ = {1, 2, …}

for example if `now()` is `2016-11-15 13:15:00`, any record having create_date as below is expected to be returned.

```
2010-11-15 13:15:00  -- different year
2016-02-15 13:15:00  -- different month
2016-11-15 13:46:23  -- different minute/seconds
2010-11-15 13:46:23  -- different year, month, minute and sec
```

The best simple query I could think of was this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE extract(day from age(now(), created_date)) = 0 -- same day any month ago
  AND extract(hour from age(now(), created_date)) = 0; -- same hour
```

But the problem is there are some specific days that will be left out of the query. Such as when

```
created_date=2016-01-31 13:00:00
now() is 2016-02-28 13:00:00
```

in this case, the age of the record is `28 days` instead of 1 month; according to the `age` function in Postgresql.
So it will never be fetched neither at the end of Feb, or 1st of March.

Any idea about how this problem can be addressed in the most simple way is appreciated.

---

Here's some test data you can use to verify:

```
create table mytable (created_date timestamp, expected_records int);
truncate mytable;
insert into mytable (created_date, expected_records)  values 
('2013-01-11 13:22:33', 2),
('2014-02-11 13:58:22', 2),
('2015-03-21 13:22:00', 1),
('2013-02-28 13:11:00', 5),
('2017-02-28 13:22:00', 5),
('2016-03-31 13:22:00', 5),
('2015-04-30 13:22:00', 5),
('2014-05-31 13:22:00', 5),
('2014-05-31 12:22:00', 1);
```

the final SELECT query can be executed on any of these timstamps but should returns same amount of rows as `expected_records` states.
Also you can use `'some date'::timestamp` instead of now() to fake time.

Comment: To confirm, you are counting calendar months, not sets of 30 days, etc.?

Comment: correct. @toonice i don't count 30 days, I want N months records.

Comment: Should '2010-11-15 13:46:23' (different year and minutes / seconds) be listed?

Comment: @toonice yes. :)

Comment: I'll see what I can do...

Comment: What about '2016-11-15 12:59:59' and '2016-11-15 12:15:01'?

Comment: @toonice Nope. that will be fetched in the query that ran 1 hour ago :D

Comment: Small point, but you set description should read { 0, 1, 2, ... }.

Comment: `Having Their Monthly Period` , hahahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's try to understand your requirements better. You'll need all the records, for which the timestamp column (`created_date`) & the current time (`now()`) is in the following relation:

- has the exact same hour
  **AND**

  - has the exact same day
    **OR**
  - `created_date` has a day, which is greater than `now()`'s day
    **BUT** only if `now()` is in the last day of the current month.

---

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  EXTRACT(hour FROM created_date) = EXTRACT(hour FROM now())
AND    (EXTRACT(day FROM created_date) = EXTRACT(day  FROM now())
OR      CASE
          WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE + 1) <> EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_DATE)
          THEN EXTRACT(day FROM created_date) > EXTRACT(day FROM now())
          ELSE FALSE
        END)
```

http://rextester.com/TXGCSI34243

*Note*: if you want to bind `timestamp`s for your solution (not actually using the `now()` & `current_date` functions) then use `WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM ? + INTERVAL '1 day') > EXTRACT(month FROM ?)` to test whether the bound timestamp is the last day of its month, or not.

Comment: Please note that the code above is ineffective whereas the code from rextester is.  I call your attention to line 6 of both statements.

Comment: @toonice what do you mean by ineffective? They are the same.

Comment: In line 6 of the above you are testing on `current_date` to see if it is at the end of the month, whereas you should be testing `NOW()` (as you are in the restester code).

Comment: @toonice in the rextester code I test literal values, not function calls (obviously, because the edge-case already passed now). I use `timestamp '2017-02-28 13:00:00'` for `now()` and `date '2017-02-28'` for `current_date` which was true at `2017-02-28 13:00:00`. Yes, technically OP could use `now()` too (with the note in my answer), but using `current_date` achieves the same thing.

Comment: The literal value is used as a substitute for `NOW()` so that we may test the sample data without having to adjust the sample data so that we will get a suitable spread of results in relation to the current time / date.  If you substitute the literal value into your above expression then run the code, you will get the wrong results, i.e. you do not get the desired effect.  You get the right results with the rextester code.

Comment: @toonice actually, the rextester wasn't good enough either. I don't know however that spotted the same thing or not. now, the formula is equivalent  to yours http://rextester.com/EDNL16799

Answer (score 1):

You can workaround by getting the first month day - (1 day):

**sample:**

```
t=# create table so42(t timestamp);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so42 select '2016-05-31 13:00:00';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so42 select '2016-10-31 13:00:00';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so42 select '2016-02-29 13:00:00';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so42 select '2016-01-21 13:00:00';
INSERT 0 1
```

**join example:**

```
t=# with ts as (
        select
                generate_series('2016-01-01 13:00:00'::timestamp,'2016-12-01'::date,'1 month'::interval)
                - '1 day'::interval
        lastday
)
select t
from so42
join ts on ts.lastday = t
;
          t
---------------------
 2016-02-29 13:00:00
 2016-05-31 13:00:00
 2016-10-31 13:00:00
(3 rows)
```

also you can **wrap it up into function** with argument, smth like:

```
t=# create or replace function so45(_ts timestamp) returns table (lastday timestamp) as
$$
declare
 _start timestamp;
 _stop timestamp;
begin
 select date_trunc('year', _ts) + (_ts)::time +concat(extract(day from _ts),' days')::interval into _start;
 select date_trunc('year', _ts) + (_ts)::time +concat(extract(day from _ts),' days')::interval + '12 month'::interval into _stop;
return query with ts as (
        select
                generate_series(_start,_stop,'1 month'::interval)
                - '1 day'::interval
        lastday
)
select * from ts order by 1;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

**join example:**

```
t=# with ts as (select so45('2016-03-31 13:00:00'))
select t
from so42
join ts on ts.so45 = t
;
          t
---------------------
 2016-02-29 13:00:00
 2016-05-31 13:00:00
 2016-10-31 13:00:00
(3 rows)

t=# with ts as (select so45('2016-03-21 13:00:00'))
select t
from so42
join ts on ts.so45 = t
;
          t
---------------------
 2016-01-21 13:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: It actually not quite true because at the end i want to run this query every hour and i expect different results rather than every month.
Plus, even it can be adjustable that way, it seems have some left out days as well. for instance if you exec this query: `SELECT generate_series('2016-01-31 13:00:00'::timestamp,'2018-01-31'::DATE,'1 month'::interval) - '1 day'::interval lastday;` you'll see a what's happening after `2017-02-27`

Comment: please check out the function in my answer. I created it based on your statement that you have exact day and hour to compare against. You can't use any date as argument to `generate_series` for logic to work (that's why I decided to wrap logic into function) - try the function with the date that confuses you and please tell if it works

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but I have updated my question providing some sample to test & verify.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code segment, which has been tested and confirmed as effective...

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE EXTRACT( HOUR FROM NOW() ) = EXTRACT( HOUR FROM created_date )
  AND ( ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date ) ) OR

        ( EXTRACT( DAY FROM DATE_TRUNC( 'MONTH', NOW() ) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY' ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() ) AND
          EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date ) >= EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() ) ) );
```

The following code tests to see both dates have the same days figure, irrespective of if one of them is the end of its month.  In that situation no further testing of the dates is required...

```
EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date )
```

The following code tests if `NOW()` is at the end of the month...

```
EXTRACT( DAY FROM DATE_TRUNC( 'MONTH', NOW() ) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY' ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() )
```

The following code tests to see if `created_date` has a days value that is greater than `NOW()`'s...

```
EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date ) >= EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() )
```

Thus if the end of `NOW()` has no greater a value than the day value of `created_date` then they can be considered equivalent (hence the following code)  e.g. `NOW()`'s date = 2017-02-28 versus `created_date`'s 2017-01-31, or `NOW()`'s date = 2017-04-30 versus `created_date`'s 2017-12-31, etc.

```
EXTRACT( DAY FROM DATE_TRUNC( 'MONTH', NOW() ) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY' ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() ) AND
EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date ) >= EXTRACT( DAY FROM NOW() )
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but I have updated my question, providing some sample to test & verify.

Comment: I have tested my code with the sample tables and data you provided, as well as a few extra rows that should or should not produce results based upon my current date and time.  It appears to work as specified.  If it does not then please provide a descriptive error report.

Comment: `SELECT  *
FROM mytable
WHERE EXTRACT( HOUR FROM '2017-02-28 13:22:00'::timestamp ) = EXTRACT( HOUR FROM created_date )
  AND EXTRACT( DAY FROM '2017-02-28 13:22:00'::timestamp ) = EXTRACT( DAY FROM created_date );` should returns 5 rows while it returns 2.

Comment: I have examined the sample data you provided in the revised question.  All but one match on the hours figure, but only two of those match on the day figure (the fourth and fifth rows).

Comment: that is exactly the problem :)
Feb 2017 has 28 days while Jan has 31 days.
so logically, when we are @ 31 Jan 2017 and we say 1 month later, it means 28 Feb 2017 and vice versa.

Comment: I see the problem.  I shall solve it when I get back from dinner.  I should be an hour or so.